# oracle query using Union All

Tags: oracle

Need to get room type wise female and male count, below is my query

```
 (SELECT  WARD,ROOMTYPE ,FEMALE,MALE
 FROM
(SELECT NS.WARD,RC.ROOMTYPE,(DECODE(IP.GENDER,'F',COUNT(IP.HNO)))FEMALE,(DECODE(IP.GENDER,'M',COUNT(IP.HNO)))MALE FROM BEDSHIFT R,BED B,NURSTATION NS,PATIENTS IP,ROOMTYPE RT,ROOMCATEGORY RC 
 WHERE R.BD_CODE=B.BD_CODE AND B.NS_CODE=NS.NS_CODE AND R.IP_NO=IP.IP_NO AND R.RMC_OCCUPBY='B' 
 AND B.RT_CODE=RT.RT_CODE AND RT.RC_CODE=RC.RC_CODE
 AND IP.IPC_STATUS IS NULL AND R.RMC_RELESETYPE IS NULL GROUP BY RC.ROOMTYPE,NS.WARD,IP.GENDER
UNION ALL
SELECT NS.WARD,RC.ROOMTYPE,(DECODE(IP.GENDER,'F',COUNT(IP.HNO)))FEMALE,(DECODE(IP.GENDER,'M',COUNT(IP.HNO)))MALE FROM PATIENTS IP,BED BD,NURSTATION NS,ROOMTYPE RT,ROOMCATEGORY RC  
 WHERE IP.BD_CODE=BD.BD_CODE 
 AND BD.RT_CODE=RT.RT_CODE AND RT.RC_CODE=RC.RC_CODE
 AND BD.NS_CODE=NS.NS_CODE AND IP.IPC_STATUS IS NULL GROUP BY RC.ROOMTYPE,NS.WARD,IP.GENDER)
  T 
 GROUP BY FEMALE,MALE,WARD,ROOMTYPE) ORDER BY WARD
```

returns below

[image]

need to get it as

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group only once and sum the males and females:

```
SELECT WARD, ROOMTYPE, sum(FEMALE), sum(MALE)
  FROM (SELECT NS.WARD,
               RC.ROOMTYPE,
               IP.GENDER, 'F', COUNT(IP.HNO))) FEMALE,
               IP.GENDER, 'M', COUNT(IP.HNO))) MALE
          FROM BEDSHIFT     R,
               BED          B,
               NURSTATION   NS,
               PATIENTS     IP,
               ROOMTYPE     RT,
               ROOMCATEGORY RC
         WHERE R.BD_CODE = B.BD_CODE
           AND B.NS_CODE = NS.NS_CODE
           AND R.IP_NO = IP.IP_NO
           AND R.RMC_OCCUPBY = 'B'
           AND B.RT_CODE = RT.RT_CODE
           AND RT.RC_CODE = RC.RC_CODE
           AND IP.IPC_STATUS IS NULL
           AND R.RMC_RELESETYPE IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NS.WARD,
               RC.ROOMTYPE,
               (DECODE(IP.GENDER, 'F', COUNT(IP.HNO))) FEMALE,
               (DECODE(IP.GENDER, 'M', COUNT(IP.HNO))) MALE
          FROM PATIENTS     IP,
               BED          BD,
               NURSTATION   NS,
               ROOMTYPE     RT,
               ROOMCATEGORY RC
         WHERE IP.BD_CODE = BD.BD_CODE
           AND BD.RT_CODE = RT.RT_CODE
           AND RT.RC_CODE = RC.RC_CODE
           AND BD.NS_CODE = NS.NS_CODE
           AND IP.IPC_STATUS IS NULL) T
 GROUP BY WARD, ROOMTYPE
 ORDER BY WARD
```

This way the query **should be faster**, than grouping three times, or even fourtimes. You could also use subqueries for males and females, which could be even faster without grouping at all (without seeing the schema, I wouldn't give you the query).

Comment: @user2119324 Just sum COUNT(IP.HNO)

Answer (score 1):

change first line

```
(SELECT  WARD,ROOMTYPE ,SUM(FEMALE) AS FEMALE, SUM(MALE) AS MALE
```

and last line

```
GROUP BY WARD,ROOMTYPE) ORDER BY WARD,ROOMTYPE
```